# SharePoint hosted-add in save date object in list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, jsom, sharepoint-hosted-app, date

What is the best way to save date object in SPO list with **JSOM**? because date where is saved is not correct

**This is my code(experiments)**

```
//This is my date string where i get from datepiker - **25/01/2017** --> $("#holidayDateFromValue").val()

var dtTest = new Date(moment($("#holidayDateFromValue").val(), 'DD.MM.YYYY'));

var dt = new Date(dtTest.getFullYear(), dtTest.getMonth(), dtTest.getDay());
```

**But date where is saved in list is:** 03/01/2017

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: Please add proper question if you find any solution to your question is large.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the method getDay(). That method will give you the day of the week in this case 3. You should be using the method getDate().

```
var dt = new Date(dtTest.getFullYear(), dtTest.getMonth(), dtTest.getDate());
```

-Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll try, moment :)